# How to use modal dialog of bootstrap to prevent default on angular -$locationChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use modal dialog of bootstrap to ask for confirmation to navigate when the page is in edit mode.

I am using `$locationChangeStart` event to find out change in navigation. I am using a bool flag to find if the current page is in edit mode. In edit mode I should show the modal dialog on `$locationChangeStart` event trigger.

The dialog would contain Yes(To navigate away from the current page) or No(to stay on the same page).

I have used bootstrap modal dialog. My code would look like:

This is inside controller:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

                if (vm.isEditMode) {

                    event.preventDefault();
            }
```

I have created a angular directive for modal dialog. How would I call `event.preventDefault()` inside directive, on click of "No" by the user?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Perhaps a code example would clarify.

Comment: You can check my answer for a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34036193/2048375) question