# $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart') and $modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJs application that is detecting the change of the state (using ui.router) to present the user with the option to save unsaved changes. Now I'm doing this with a confirm dialog:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => {
    if (self.changed && confirm('There are unsaved changes. Do you want to save them?'))
        this.save();
});
```

I wanted to change it to using the `$modal` dialog from the bootstrap ui library. The problem I have is that as the `$modal.open()` call returns inmediatelly (being asynchronous) the state changes before opening the dialog and it's never opened.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => {
    if (self.changed)
       this.$dialog.open({...}).result.then(()=>{
            this.save();
        });
});
```

Is there a way to overcome this problem or am I stuck to using the plain javascript confirm dialog?

Comment: what triggers the state change? Likely need to catch it there and not even enter into the change

Comment: It might be a ui-sref link or a manual state change via `$state.go`. I want to detect when the user exits that state whichever the reason.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is prevent the event based on a flag stored perhaps on $rootScope or in a service and toggle the flag using modal events. If it was all through `$state.go()` would be much simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. In my application, I am using an AppCtrl (parent) to handle navigation, dirty state etc.

```
    function AppCtrl($rootScope, events, modalDialog) {
       var vm = this,
           handlingUnsavedChanges = false;

       function isDirty() {
            return $rootScope.$broadcast(events.CAN_DEACTIVATE).defaultPrevented;
       }

       function onStateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams) {
            if (handlingUnsavedChanges) {
                // if the dirty state has already been checked then continue with the state change
                return;
            }

            // check for dirty state
            if (isDirty()) {
                // cancel navigation
                event.preventDefault();
                modalDialog
                    .confirmNavigation()
                    .then(function () {
                        // ignore changes
                        handlingUnsavedChanges = true;
                        $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
                    });
            } 
            // Else let the state change
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', onStateChangeStart);
    }

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
   <div ui-view />
</div>
```

Then you can add an event handler for CAN_DEACTIVATE event in your route controller to check for dirty state, for example

```
    function UserDetailCtrl($scope, events) {
        function isDirty() {
            // Your logic, return a boolean
        }

        function canDeactivate(e) {
            if (isDirty()) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        $scope.$on(events.CAN_DEACTIVATE, canDeactivate);
    }
```

Comment: @CarlesCompany, @AmanMahajan, I'm adding my version of answer below because I'm not very comfortable with using `broadcast` at this moment. Please suggest if my approach is correct.

Comment: @AmanMahajan, I added `stateChangeStart` listener in my service.  It can be added at any place correct?

Answer (score 4):

**You can do it perfectly fine with `ui-router` and settings in `run` section of your app.**

The crucial part is basically watching the `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` event. 
I present the whole solution with the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RRWvvy?p=preview The main part is in `scipt.js`, and it goes as follows:

```
routerApp.run(function($rootScope, $uibModal, $state) {
  $rootScope.modal = false; // this has to be set so the modal is not loaded constantly, and skips the 1st application entrance

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

      if ($rootScope.modal) {
        event.preventDefault(); //this stops the transition
        $rootScope.modal = false;
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'modal.html'
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
          console.log('changing state to:'+ toState.name);
          $state.go(toState, {}, {reload:true});
        }, function() {
          console.log('going back to state:'+ fromState.name);
          $state.go(fromState, {}, {reload:true});
        });
      } else {
        $rootScope.modal = true;
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should listen the `$locationChangeStart` event and if you have unsaved changes then do `event.prventDefault()` and continue on with your logic for the confirmation dialog with `ui-bootstrap modal`. The thing is that the order of the events is slightly changed in the newer angular versions and the `$stateChangeStart` happens a little too late to do your logic there. If you get stuck I can provide you with working example. For now, here is sample code:

```js
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', () => {
    if (self.changed) {
       event.preventDefault();
       this.$dialog.open({...}).result.then(()=>{
            this.save();
            // your logic for the redirection if needed after the save
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with state change event , it would be better to apply the event on app and use $modal service. You can find a detailed explanation of this here

http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html

However this gives an example that works for each state change whenever state changes but you can make it working for the single or specified states like this :

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
  if(toState.name =="desiredState") {
  event.preventDefault();
  // perform your task here
  }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not very comfortable with using `broadcast` I used below approach.

I simply cancel current event (state change) before showing my `JQuery` Dialog.  And if user selects 'yes', then i trigger `$state.go`, if selects 'cancel/no'- we don't need to do anything, we already cancelled event.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

    console.log('$stateChangeStart- fromState= '+fromState.name +'-toState= '+toState.name);

    /*If user starts to change state, show him a confirmation dialog
     * If user selects 'Yes' - continue with state change and go in pause mode for collection.
     * If user selects 'No'- stop state change.
     */
    if (/*some condition*/) {                    


        /*stateChangeStart gets triggered again by $state.go initiated from our modal dialog-
        hence avoid extra cycle of listening to stateChangeStart*/
        if (service.stateChangeTriggeredByDialog) {
            service.stateChangeTriggeredByDialog = false;
            return;
        }

        if (fromParams.paramName !== toParams.paramName) {
            event.preventDefault();                        

            Dialog.confirm({
                dialogClass: 'my-customDialog',
                template: $translate.instant('STATE_CHANGE_MSG'),
                resizable: false,
                width: 550                            
            }).then(function () {   
                console.log('User choose to continue state change');  
                service.stateChangeTriggeredByDialog = true;
                $state.go(toState, toParams, { inherit: false });
            }, function () {
                console.log('User choose to stop state change');                            
            });                                            
        }
    }});
```